# Clone / Remove TR Row - Almost working

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm using the code I found in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgpLmzau/1/) and it is almost perfect for what I need.

The code allows me to clone another TR and have the option to delete the cloned rows.

The issue I have is I don't want to be able to delete all rows.

How do I stop the script from deleting the first row ?

I have tried :

```
var numItems = $('.DeleteBoxRow').length
if (numItems >1) {
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

but this seems a bit hit and miss.

I'm also finding that if I add then delete rows, I get an issue in I can't add again.

Any advice how to sort this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dynamic elements use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is used since in the fiddle jQuery 1.6 is used, if you are using jQuery >= 1.7 use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#BoxTable').delegate('.DeleteBoxRow:not(#TemplateRow .DeleteBoxRow)', 'click', function() {

        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

also need to change the id of the cloned row because ID of an element must be unique. also in the above selector we are excluding `.DeleteBoxRow` elements within element with id `TemplateRow` so if there are any other row with that id there too the delete won't work

```
var $newRow = $('#TemplateRow').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d1mjfbra/)